# Add class to dynamically created HTML node

Tags: javascript

I thought this was going to be a bit easier to do, but I have spent a good 2 hours on it, without being able to figure it out.

I have this output:

```html
<div class="cart-contents">
  Your shopping cart is empty
</div>
```

and I am dynamically creating about 5 spans with JS:

```js
function outputValue(value){
 //output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + value;
 output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "<span>" + value + "</span>";
}
```

so my last span div is a total. I created a CSS class of .total to change a few styles, I tried few things like output.classList.addClass(.total);

How can I dynamically add a class to just the last span?

this would be my output:

```js
var output = document.querySelector(".cart-contents");
var total;

function outputValue(value){
 //output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + value;
 output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "<span>" + value + "</span>";
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-contents">
 Your shopping cart is empty
  //<span>would go here</span>
  //<span>would go here</span>
  //<span>would go here</span>
  //<span>would go here</span>
  //<span class="total">would go here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `output`? Will this span be the last element child of `output`?

Comment: I changed the post to reflect it, but the output would go inside the dive .cart-contents

Comment: how do you call `outputValue` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target the last span and add the class with javascript, you'd use a selector, like `span:last-child`, that gets the last span inside `output`, and then you'd use `classList.add()`.
There is no `addClass()`, that's a jQuery method.

```
output.querySelector('span:last-child').classList.add('total')
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/xbox618g/)

Comment: Thanks Adeneo. That worked for me. I was doing a variation of this, but was not using the querySelector.

Comment: @Lucky500 - Note that  there are many other ways to get the last span as well, for instance `output.lastChild` or `output.lastElementChild` or any number of CSS 2.1 selectors in `querySelector` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fix for the problem, but this removes the problem:
You can do this in pure CSS, using the last-of-type selector. This is the best solution IMHO.
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMOXqK
Since this doesn't even need JavaScript, and only uses CSS without complicated selectors, this seems like the best solution.

Possible fixes for your problem:
Your addClassList syntax is incorrect.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

```
output.classList.add("total");
```

This is the correct addClass syntax.

Is there any reason why you would add the class with JavaScript, instead of adding it instantly? If you would pass an (optional) class parameter, you could pass the class when adding the totals (assuming you know when you're adding the totals).

```
function outputValue(value){
    outputValue(value,"");
}

function outputValue(value, class){
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "<span class='" + class + "'>" + value + "</span>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did try to use the last of type selector, like this .cart-contents:last-of-type { font-weight: bold;}, but it change all the contents....maybe because they are being generated dynamically?

Comment: You need to specify the span type. Right now you're selecting the last shopping cart type. Example:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMOXqK