# Add class to innerHTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I fail to add a `class` using JS to an `innerHTML` element:

```
var el = document.createElement("a");
el.href = `/${someurl}/`;
el.innerHTML = `<img src="${someimg}"></img>`;
el.innerHTML.className = `testclassimage`;
```

This results in:

```
<a href="/someurl/"><img src="https://..."></a>
```

I also tried with:

```
el.innerHTML.insertAdjacentHTML(`class="testclassimage"`)
```

but the result is the same. How can I add a class to the `<img>`?

Comment: There is no `innerHTML` attribute. `innerHTML` adds the HTML to the element So change the HTML that you add to the element before setting `innerHTML`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add class to dynamically created HTML node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509504/add-class-to-dynamically-created-html-node)

Comment: `innerHTML` only gets or sets html strings. Once you set that string it gets turned into DOM objects and you need methods like `Element.querySelector()` to target the actual elements created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the same way as you did with the "src" attribute e.g

```
var el = document.createElement("a");
el.href = `/${someurl}/`;
el.innerHTML = `<img src="${someimg}" class="testclassimage"></img>`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `innerHTML` in the first place.

Instead, like you did with the `a`, use `document.createElement` to create the image along with `element.appendChild` to place in in the anchor:

```js
const anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'https://example.com';

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150';
img.className = `testclassimage`;

anchor.appendChild(img);

document.body.appendChild(anchor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your class directly to html string like below:

```
el.innerHTML = `<img class="myClassName" src="${someimg}"></img>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the class to the inner element during creation

```
el.innerHTML = `<img src="${someimg}" class="myClass"></img>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you can easily achieve adding class to the image tag.

```js
const someURL = "example.com";
const someIMG = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/160/200/200.jpg?hmac=0fql9ogVWlCf8ddvQCF-vGiiso9i0m0A68TP5De28tI";

var ele = document.createElement("a");

ele.href = `${someURL}`;

ele.innerHTML = `<img src="${someIMG}" class="testclassimage"></img>`;


document.body.appendChild(ele);
```

```css
.testclassimage {
  border: 10px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I would suggest:

```
var el = document.createElement("a");
el.href = `/${someurl}/`;
el.innerHTML = `<img src="${someimg}"></img>`;
el.childNodes[0].className = `testclassimage`;
```

You are setting className to the first child of *el*, which in your case is an image element.